# The turtle module is not allowing me to end the game

Tags: python, 2d, python-turtle

So I've implemented pretty much all the logic needed for the snake game and it is running okay for the most part. the main problem is when the game should end and it doesn't. tried **turtle.done** but still nothing is working for some reason. if you could help me solve this issue that would be wonderful. thank you.

Edit: I also find out that there is a bug when the snake collides with the wall. if the snake was at "default" length then the game will end. otherwise, it just doesn't detect the wall to begin with. or while walking far from the wall the game would suddenly end and the message "GAME OVER" would show. not sure what the main issue is to be honest.

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle
from random import randint


class Snake:
    def __init__(self, grid_size, initial_x_positions):
        self.segments = []
        self.grid_size = grid_size
        self.create_snake(initial_x_positions)
        self.head = self.segments[0]

    def create_snake(self, initial_x_positions):
        for x in initial_x_positions:
            self.add_segment(x)

    def add_segment(self, position):
        segment = turtle.Turtle("square")
        segment.color("RoyalBlue")
        segment.speed('slowest')
        segment.penup()
        segment.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(segment)

    def extend(self):
        self.add_segment(self.segments[-1].position())

    def move(self):
        for i in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):
            x_pos = self.segments[i - 1].xcor()
            y_pos = self.segments[i - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[i].goto(x_pos, y_pos)
        self.head.forward(self.grid_size)

    def up(self):
        if self.head.heading() != 270:
            self.head.setheading(90)

    def down(self):
        if self.head.heading() != 90:
            self.head.setheading(270)

    def left(self):
        if self.head.heading() != 0:
            self.head.setheading(180)

    def right(self):
        if self.head.heading() != 180:
            self.head.setheading(0)


class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.penup()
        self.color('red3')
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.reset_food_location()

    def reset_food_location(self):
        random_x_pos = randint(-250, 250)
        random_y_pos = randint(-250, 250)
        self.goto(random_x_pos, random_y_pos)


class ScoreBoard(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.color('snow')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 250)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.increase_score()

    def increase_score(self):
        self.clear()
        self.write(f"Score: {self.score}", align='center', font=('Courier', 24, 'bold'))
        self.score += 15

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write('GAME OVER', align='center', font=('Courier', 24, 'bold'))


def create_screen():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.tracer(0)
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("Snake Game")
    screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
    return screen


def control_snake_movement(screen, snake):
    screen.listen()
    screen.onkey(key="Up", fun=snake.up)
    screen.onkey(key="Down", fun=snake.down)
    screen.onkey(key="Left", fun=snake.left)
    screen.onkey(key="Right", fun=snake.right)


def main():
    initial_x_position = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
    grid_size = 20
    frame_delay_ms = 80

    screen = create_screen()
    snake = Snake(grid_size, initial_x_position)
    control_snake_movement(screen, snake)
    food = Food()
    scoreboard = ScoreBoard()

    def tick():
        snake.move()
        screen.update()

        # Detect Collision With Food
        if snake.head.distance(food) < 20:
            food.reset_food_location()
            snake.extend()
            scoreboard.increase_score()

        # Detect Collision With Wall
        if snake.head.xcor() == 280 or snake.head.xcor() == -280 \
                or snake.head.ycor() == 280 or snake.head.ycor() == -280:
            scoreboard.game_over()
            turtle.done()

        # Detect Collision With Tail
        for segment in snake.segments[1:]:
            if snake.head.distance(segment) < 10:
                scoreboard.game_over()
                turtle.done()
        turtle.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)

    tick()
    screen.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In the `tick()` function, don't call `turtle.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)` when the game is over.

Comment: @Johhny Mopp What should I do instead?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In the `tick()` function, don't call `turtle.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)` when the game is over. You can move that call to the end of the function and set a flag that determines whether or not it should be called.

```
def tick():
    snake.move()
    screen.update()

    # Flag
    game_over = False

    # Detect Collision With Food
    if snake.head.distance(food) < 20:
        food.reset_food_location()
        snake.extend()
        scoreboard.increase_score()

    # Detect Collision With Wall
    if snake.head.xcor() == 300 or snake.head.xcor() == -300 \
            or snake.head.ycor() == 300 or snake.head.ycor() == -300:
        scoreboard.game_over()
        game_over = True   # Set flag

    # Detect Collision With Tail
    for segment in snake.segments[1:]:
        if snake.head.distance(segment) < 10:
            scoreboard.game_over()
            game_over = True   # Set flag
            break

    # Only call if game is NOT over
    if not game_over:
        turtle.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your solution, but for some reason when I run the game the screen freezes immediately. not sure why tbh.

Comment: Yes, that's odd. It works fine for me with the code from your original post.